# Place 3 HTML div; 1 left 2 right

Tags: css, html

following problem:

I have 3 divs.

```
<div id="div1"> </div>

<div id="div2"> </div>

<div id="div3"> </div>
```

And I want to place them in the following order:

DIV1 DIV2
DIV1 DIV2
DIV1 DIV2

........DIV3
........DIV3
........DIV3

One div on the left and 2 divs on the right underneath.
When I give the first two divs a float: left it looks like this:

DIV1 DIV2
DIV1 DIV2
DIV1 DIV2
DIV3
DIV3
DIV3

With "clear: left; float: right;" on the third div i get this:

DIV1 DIV2
DIV1 DIV2
DIV1 DIV2



.....................................DIV3
.....................................DIV3
.....................................DIV3

div 3 is here on the bottom of the page;

How can I place the last div underneath the second one?

Kai

Comment: use a css grid [example](http://gridpak.com/)

Comment: css clear:left; float:right; on div3

Comment: Can you change your markup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UAGwd/)**

Change your markup. Add `div1` to one element, and `div2` and `div3` to another one:

```
<div class="left">
    <div id="div1">
        <p>DIV 1</p>
        <p>DIV 1</p>
        <p>DIV 1</p>
        <p>DIV 1</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="right">
    <div id="div2">
        <p>DIV 2</p>
        <p>DIV 2</p>
        <p>DIV 2</p>
        <p>DIV 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="div3">
        <p>DIV 3</p>
        <p>DIV 3</p>
        <p>DIV 3</p>
        <p>DIV 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then float left and right:

```
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Although I changes the float right to a float left.

Answer (score 2):

Try this jfiddle, 2 columns with float and divs in it 
http://jsfiddle.net/AnFPa/1/

```
<div style="float: left;">
    <div>div1</div>
</div>
<div style="float: left;">
<div>div2</div>
<div>div3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try using clear left :

```
<div 3 style="clear:left" ></div>
```

or you can have both divs inside a container and float the bottom row to the right:

```
<div>
  <div id="1" style="float:left"></div>
  <div id="2" style="float:left"></div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
  <div id="3" style="float:right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="div4">

<div id="div1"> </div>

<div id="div2"> </div>

<div id="div3"> </div>

</div>
```

Give div 4 a width and float div 3 right.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="height: 100px; Width: 200px;"> <!-- Container -->
        <div style="float:left; height: 50px; Width:100px; background-color:red;">
        </div>
        <div style="float:left; height: 50px; Width:100px; background-color:blue;">
        </div>
        <div style="float:right; height: 50px; Width:100px; background-color:green;">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```